# How to implement batch insert using spring-data-jdbc

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jdbc

is it possible to implement batch insert using spring-data-jdbc somehow? Or can i get access to JDBCTemplate using this spring-data realization?

Answer (score 4):

There is currently no support for batch operations. 
There are two issues requesting that one might want to follow if one is interested in that feature: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJDBC-328 and https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJDBC-314

If one is working with Spring Data JDBC there will always be a `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` in the application context so one can get that injected in order to perform batch operations without any additional configuration.

Comment: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJDBC-328 is now marked as duplicate of https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJDBC-314, and the latter has been implemented as of July 4, 2022.